# Parse multiple JSON in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json

Long story, short. I need to access just the parent in the JSON file.
[How to parse multiple json in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245158/how-to-parse-multiple-json-in-objective-c) )
I need to access the **author > NAME** from this JSON. (*removed link)

The code is:

```
NSURL *blogURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"*removed link"];

    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogURL];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
//    NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionary);

    self.blogPosts = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSArray *blogPostsArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"posts"];

    for (NSDictionary *bpDictionary in blogPostsArray) {
        BlogPost *blogPost = [BlogPost blogPostWithTitle:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"title"]];
        blogPost.author = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"author"];
        blogPost.thumbnail = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
        blogPost.date = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"date"];
        blogPost.url = [NSURL URLWithString:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"url"]];
        [self.blogPosts addObject:blogPost];
    }
```

How can i make it access that value ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the dot notation

JSON

```
{
    "author": {
                "name" : "mckeejm"
              }
}
```

Objective C:

```
blogPost.author = [bpDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"author.name"];
```

**updated** Thanks @Martin

Comment: `valueForKey:` is a KVC method, the correct way to access an object stored in a dictionary is via `objectForKey:`

Comment: You probably meant `valueForKeyPath`.